# ACK message (hex to ASCII)

Tags: c#, server, udp, sms, ascii

I am trying to acknowledge the message received and want to match it with the code My program sent.

SMS output is in this format `<<<phonenumber,ASCII,5,436865636b>>>`

I want to isolate phone number and the message after 5, and convert it to ASCII

I already have a UDP server.

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED:

```
            var ascii = string.Empty;

            for (var i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                var hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                var decval = Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
                var character = Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;
            }

            return ascii;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regex` to deal with pattern text extraction.

```
var message = @"<<<phonenumber,ASCII,5,436865636b>>>";
var pattern = @"<<<(?<phoneNumber>\w+),ASCII,5,(?<value>\w+)>>>";
var match = Regex.Match(message, pattern);

var phoneNumber = match.Groups["phoneNumber"].Value;
var value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
```